# Add Rich Text Full Editor to Sitecore Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

I know there is a web.config Sitecore setting that will update the default text editor within the content editor for Sitecore to use the full text editor:

```
<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full" />
```

However, this does not provide the full rich text editor toolbar within Page Editor Mode. Is there another setting that I am missing or is this implemented differently?

Answer (score 6):

Add the `/sitecore/system/Settings/HTML Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full` to the source field in   the Builder tab when in template Manager mode.

Answer (score 1):

When in page editor the "rich text" field will have the buttons in the folder WebEdit under your DefaultProfile eg. /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full.

However you will get the normal Page Editor opened in a popup window if you click the leftmost button "Edit the text", when you have selected the field. There you will have your full profile (if selected as default).

I don't think all the buttons work in page editor, so I would recommend you school the editors to use the popup, which they also do when using the Content Editor.

Comment: Thanks, I knew the functionality exists there, but I am trying to bring the full text editor experience directly into the Page Editor. I am currently working with Sitecore support as well. Will keep you posted with what I find.

Comment: The menu has predefined icons for Rich Text profiles that are defined in the Core database under the /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full/WebEdit Buttons item. To customize it, additional buttons and custom code can be added.